# Unable to load my csv file to my rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to load my csv file to my rails database using postgresql engine.However, it returns an `empty array` when I test with `postman` to `GET` the data from my `database`.

My ruby code implemented in my lib directory:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('lib/seeds/glints.csv', headers: true, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1', col_sep: ';') do |row|
  new_empty_aaray = []
  new_empty_aaray << row.to_h

  puts new_empty_aaray
end

puts "There are now #{AllRestaurant.count} rows in the all_restaurants table"
```

I then run `rails db:seed` to seed the data to database

my controller:

```
class AllRestaurantsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_all_restaurant, only: [:show]
  def index
    @all_restaurants = AllRestaurant.all
    render json: @all_restaurants
  end

  def show
    render json: @all_restaurant
  end

  private

  def find_all_resstaurant
    @all_restaurant = AllRestaurant.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

path to the csv file in the lib folder `lib/seeds/glints.csv`

I really don't know what I'm missing

Comment: Hello Eric, welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to use [markdown][1] to format your question or answer next time you post. It seems that either `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.js` or `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss` does not exist in your project. Can you check if that's the case?


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Why are you trying to import a stylesheet into a javascript file anyway?